# Ubuntu autosuspends when CPU/GPU temperature reached 90°-92° C

Tags: suspend, overheating, temperature

I've been using Ubuntu for 2 days, and when I want to play Overwatch through Lutris, I can't. When I'm playing, the temperature is very high (~94° C on the GPU), and Ubuntu is suspending my laptop. I checked `dmesg` and it's just entering suspend (deep) without any warnings. Is there any way to solve it? Solve autosuspend, not overheating. And Arch-based distros aren't doing this, only Ubuntu and Ubuntu-based distros like KDE Neon.

[image]

Comment: This sounds like a thermal shutdown which should not be happening if your hardware cooling is functioning properly. A system should be able to run at 100% resources indefinitely without reaching Tmax. You may need to open up your laptop and clean out the dust. If it's an older laptop, you may need to remove the heatsink, remove the old thermal compound and apply new thermal compound.

Comment: if its thermal shoutdown, then why its happening only on ubuntu?
also not shutdown, its just entering suspend(deep)

Comment: I don't think that can be answered based on the information. Maybe something is using your CPU or GPU more? It's hard to compare resource usage between two different systems with a completely different stack. Have you tried to keep up a resource monitor to see if any applications are taking up an outsized amount of resources? In any case, a thermal stop isn't normal. Laptops are designed to handle being pushed to the limit, especially a laptop with a dedicated GPU, but dust and drying thermal compound can definitely degrade cooling performance over time.

Comment: yeah, i tried to monitor system resource usage, and ubuntu is even better here.
also i checked journalctl, it just said "suspend button pressed"

Comment: Oh now that's very curious. We can definitely rule out that a power button was pressed deliberately... What is the exact line in journalctl? Maybe we can find some documentation about what conditions would cause that log to appear.

Comment: https://yapx.ru/album/V6N3e here.

Comment: It's definitely temperature related because your computer is overheating. My CPU and GPU both run 30-35° C, not higher

Comment: @karel 30-35 on a non idle system? My laptop seldom is below 50 and I am not playing any games (then again 30 is just 5 degrees above room-temperature) and I use displaylink.

Comment: non-idle, are you kidding me? It's working all the time. It is however a custom hardware build.

Comment: first of all, i have a thin laptop.
it definitely normal temperatures for it and i know it. (i watched tests and etc)
also i said that only ubuntu doing this, then why its temperature related??